# LDAP authentication is not working after upgrading to ReviewBoard 2.0

Tags: python, ldap, upgrade, review-board

After upgrading to ReviewBoard 2.0 from 1.7 it seems that the LDAP authetication method simply disappeared.. By disappeared I mean it's not a backend anymore:

[image]

`python-ldap` is installed:

```
>>> import ldap
>>> ldap.__version__
'2.4.15'
```

When I start an interactive shell however the LDAP backend is not present in the list of `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`:

```
>>> reviewboard.accounts.backends.get_backends()
[<reviewboard.accounts.backends.StandardAuthBackend object at 0x4259190>]
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS
(u'reviewboard.accounts.backends.StandardAuthBackend',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally it was the fact that I installed the ReviewBoard using virtualenv. Not sure why but it seems that the new version somehow omitted the existing backends when not having this in the mod_wsgi file:

```
activate_this = '/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
```

Also the site configuration should have this (in django admin:   /admin/db/siteconfig/siteconfiguration/1/) :

```
"auth_backend": "ldap",
```

Hope this helps.